# Powershell - How to add user to SP Read group

Tags: permissions, groups

I have 50+ sites and I need to add a user to all those 50+ site. Is there a way to find out which sharepoint group has Read level access and add user to that group for all 50+ site?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$site=get-spsite http://sitecollection
#get web object
$web=$site.RootWeb

#Enumarate site groups
$web.SiteGroups |select name
#get user object
$user=$web.EnsureUser("domain\XXXX")
#Get group object
$group=$web.SiteGroups["Test Visitors"]
#add user to group
$group.AddUser($user)
```